# Dompdf Tempremental Behavior

Tags: dompdf

DomPDF Version: 0.5.1 -
Server PHP Version: 5.x.x

On my client's website the PDF is generated fine when using Safari on a Mac. When using any other browser the PDF won't download at all.

I am wondering if this is something common?

The page I have tested on is: http://www.jamesproperties.co.uk/propertydetails.php?ref=10493&prop=1&pmin=0&pmax=10000000&bmin=0&bmax=100&proptype=0&search=0&order=DESC&page=1

Then clicking 'Print Property Details' (below the gallery).

Comment: Are you sure it's just because you're using Safari on Mac? I attempted to generate the PDF and was continually redirected to the "click to generate" page. Perhaps it has something to do with being logged in?

Comment: Thanks Brian. I am not logged in when generating in Safari, and am getting a rendered PDF. All other browsers on Mac and Windows are showing the page you mention above.

Comment: Something else then, but I'm at a loss. I was unable to get any browser (including Safari) to produce the PDF. When I watch the headers the browser goes first to /pdf/dompdf.php, gets a 302 redirect, and lands on /pdf/index.php. It might help to see the HTTP headers you get in Safari when you successfully generate the PDF. At the very least, what is the URL you land on?

Comment: I land on the same page as you now 'index.php'. Its not even producing in Safari for me now. 

Another developer mentioned something about MIME TYPES but I'm not sure how to implement.

Comment: dompdf handles the necessary headers for sending your PDF to the browser. Could be something in your code that's redirecting before (or after) the PDF is generated. One method of looking for where the redirect is happening is to sprinkle the rendering script with `die __LINE__;` and see how far you get. Or could be something in an .htaccess if you have one.